# Using .htaccess to rewrite dynamic subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm currently using .htaccess to rewrite on my website to create dynamic subdomains. I also use it to remove the .php extension on all pages. However, once inside the subdomain, it tries to redirect again. For example, if you went to https://admin.example.com/test, it would actually be accessing https://example.com/clients/admin/test.php. I keeping getting various 404 errors using the following .htaccess file:

```
Options +MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subdomains/(.*)/(.*) http://$1.example.com/$2 [r=301,nc]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2%{REQUEST_URI}/ -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ clients/%2/$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I keep this from redirecting to https://admin.example.com/clients/admin/test.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you probably want to turn off multiviews, that's going to mess with the whole "removing the php extension" thing

Than, you want this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

To be after your redirects, and you want to be doing the redirect status check on the actual redirects:

```
Options -Multiviews + FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^subdomains/(.*)/(.*) http://$1.example.com/$2 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2%{REQUEST_URI}/ -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clients/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ clients/%2/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is giving me a 500 error when using the subdomain rules.

Comment: @brokekidweb sorry missing a condition