# Create dynamic subdomains with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the page: `website.php` this page is used to display data from any site that users created in my system.
The parameters of the page are:

```
domain.com/website.php?s=site_name&p=page_id
```

How I can **replace** it with

```
site_name.domain.com/page_id
```

with `.htaccess` only.

I found a code for `.htaccess` but I did not understand that how this change my parameters that I do not mess with `.htaccess` normally.

I'd love to help, thanks in advance

(like http://wix.com / https://www.sitebuilder.com/)

---

I want to replace `domain.co.il/website?s=site_name&p=page_id` to `site_name.domain.co.il/page_id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic subdomain with htaccess (not redirect)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875273/dynamic-subdomain-with-htaccess-not-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example found on google and adapted to your needs :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)&p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule website.php http://%1.domain.com/$2? [R=301,L]
```

/!\ not tested

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

I just found this. It should work in your case :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /website.php?s=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?page/([0-9]+)$ /website.php?s=%1&p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: its redirect me to the sub-domain but dont work.. show me an error:
ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

Comment: See my edited answer. Thanks for your feed back (I'm learning .htaccess redirection too)

Comment: doesnt work again.. return me that the DNS of the sub domain dont found..

Comment: Did you tried with the following options ? `Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on `

Comment: Sorry... Maybe you could dig on SO or google for documentation. I found this answer on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850995/using-htaccess-to-rewrite-dynamic-subdomains

Comment: @Adrienlaber
This is not what I'm need..
I want to replace domain.co.il/website?s=site_name&p=page_id
to
site_name.domain.co.il/page_id